# Check the uploaded file content is purely of that content type

Tags: php, file-upload, drupal, drupal-7, php-5.3

If I put jpg header (1st line of a jpg file) in a HTML file and save it with jpg extension, then I can bypass the MIME type checking.
eg:

```
ÿØÿà JFIF   d d  ÿì Ducky     <  ÿî Adobe dÀ   ÿÛ „    

    
hyuhjjh

<script>
alert(hello);
</script>
```

If I save the above code as a JPG file then it can bypass the MIME type checking.

```
echo mime_content_type('x.html.jpg'); //shows 'image/jpeg'
```

---

I want the script to check the uploaded file content is purely of that content type( jpg/png or pdf or 3gp/mov). For image, document and video type.

OR doesn't contain any script.

---

Actually I need it for Drupal. So I have to use custom PHP code.
In Drupal 7.50 I have used "File Upload Secure Validator" to validate uploaded file MIME type, But it is useless for the above type of situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some library to actually **load** the file. For images I used GD to open the target image and check if it returns some reasonable height and width.

Same can be done with the other types. I guess that for video files this can be very resource-demanding, but it's the only way to be sure.